# Ошибка при запуске программы на GO. 2021/02/24 18:27:15 open /.email.json: Access is denied

Tags: golang, github, gmail, account

**Поинтересовался я программой которая проверяет на работоспособность почты. Она написано на go.**
Надеюсь тут можно оставлять ссылка на gitHub: https://github.com/Crandel/gmail_checker

Так вот, все делал по инструкции, скомпилировал я exe файл так: **go build gmail.go**
Но после запуска программы: **gmail.exe** через консоль то выходит вот такое:
**2021/02/24 18:27:15 open /.email.json: Access is denied.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете подсказать в чем дело? На githube есть инструкция, действовал по ней, но вот такая ошибка выходит.
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Искал я и в интернете, но там совершенно разные ошибки. Не знаю в чем дело.

Comment: Наверное, надо сделать `set HOME=%UserProfile%` и положить файл `.email.json` с правильным содержимым в папку пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Только вот не понимаю почему выводится только в консоль слово "SHORT".

Comment: @Hopeyer https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#gomod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по коду, проблема в этой строке

```
filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/.email.json", os.Getenv("HOME"))
```

оно пытается взять домашний каталог и в нем найти нужный файл. Но у Вас видимо Windows и там эта переменная окружения пустая. В результате получается странный путь к файлу, которого там точно нет. Что делать? попробовать ручками указать явный путь или просто написал бы так

```
filename := "email.json"
```

и этот файл будет создаваться в текущем каталоге (скорее всего).

Comment: Ваш ответ прекрасен! Работает хорошо :)
Спасибо вам.

Comment: можно просто тыкнуть треугольник вверх

Comment: Хорошо, но вот мне сейчас пишет "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга. ".

Comment: можно попробовать галочку под ответом поставить

Comment: Все сделано, спасибо за помощ.
Можете еще немного уточнить? Я вписал там данные как говорилось в инструкции но после запуска программы через cmd gmail.exe пишет просто слово "SHORT". Либо после внесение в созданный файл Json не нужно запускать программу а что то делать другое?

Comment: если оно нашло файл, то данные читаются с него. Если нет, используется фейковые данные. В консоль должно печататься слово SHORT, двоеточие и число непрочитанных писем. Но этот текст можно поменять через json файл - `short_conky`. Туда можно написать все, что нужно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Но вот в моем случаи как я понял код не работает.
Наверное из за того что данный исходник уже много лет.

Comment: в целом, он должен работать. Указанное апи в целом то доступно.